# Unable to create Primary Key index using partition scheme

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a new PK constraint using a partition scheme which comprises 3 columns. One is a a computed persisted column and is also the partition column. I am getting the below error message which is not proving very helpful. It mentions "See previous errors", but there are actually no previous errors. This is using an ***Azure SQL*** database.

**ERROR MESSAGE TEXT**

> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 168
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
>   Msg 40197, Level 20, State 1, Line 168
>   The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 8657.
>   Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 167
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

[image]

Here is a link to the DDL requested - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PO9G6ifiQeoH_rF3CFzFBszyBnWql5oq

It will ask that you request access first, which I will grant.

I've provided the script just for the table giving the problem. I've also provided another file that contains the partition function, partition scheme and alter statement (which generated the error).

Its important to note that the table contains 354, 623 records when the alter statement fails, but on an empty table is works. I would need to get it to work when data is present.

Comment: Please share the table DDL and the command you used to create the pk constraint.

Comment: @ArtBajji I've updated the post with the information requested. The scripts are saved in Google Drive, they are too big to post here as its not only the table create script but also the partition function and partition scheme and the alter statement. To simulate the issue I think you'll have to populate the table with records however. I can't provide the data I have.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also share the DDL for ImportDataTypes and Source tables?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same Msg 40197, Error Code 8657 trying to create a unique clustered index for an indexed view and placing the index on a partition scheme.
What ended up fixing the issue for me was to scale the azure sql database up.
It was initially a serverless, gen 5, 8 max vCore, 1 min vCore, 3GB min memory and 24GB max memory. I scaled the database up to 40 max vCore, 24 min vCore, 72GB min memory, and 12GB max memory and that did the trick.